# Three DIVs of which two have a dynamic width

Tags: css, html

What I am trying to is have a header image centered on the top with a different color background on either side, dynamically filling the rest of the page.  The structure would look like this:

```
<div id="Header_Container">
  <div id="Header_Left"></div>
  <div id="Header_Center"></div>
  <div id="Header_Right"></div>
</div>
```

The *Header_Center* is of `960px` and the *Header_Left* and *Header_Right* should fill either side of the image to the edge of the page and change width as the page width changes.

I can not get the CSS to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fix it using padding and box model + position : relative - it can be done without HTML Change

```
<div id="Header_Container">
  <div id="Header_Left"></div>
  <div id="Header_Right"></div>
  <div id="Header_Center"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS ( 100px is for example )

```
#Header_Container{ overflow: hidden; height: 100px; } 
#Header_Container *{ box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; } 
#Header_Left{ width: 50%; padding-right: 480px; }
#Header_Right{ margin-left: 50%; width: 50%; padding-left: 480px; position: relative; top: -100% };
#Header_Center{ margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; position: relative; top: -200%; }
```

Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/ZAALB/2/
EDITed incorrect example

Comment: Are you serious? [I don't believe you have tested it](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/ZAALB/1/).

Comment: Ooops, forgot to update example - now it is working correctgly

Comment: Well done, +1. But you should have mentioned this requires CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want those 3 divs to fill each with different content, the outsides filled fluidly or multiline. Otherwise the answer could be **much** <sup>1)</sup> more simple. I also assume that the center div defines the total height of the header.

Given these two assupmtions, still a few different scenarios are thinkable of which I will give 4 examples from which you can choose the best fitting solution.

The HTML is exactly yours.

The CSS looks like:

```
#Header_Container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#Header_Left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 480px;
}
#Header_Right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 480px;
    top: 0;
}
#Header_Center {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
}
```

Now, you could change behaviour of left and right with a few extra styles:

```
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
```

**[See demonstration fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/23pLn/)**.

<sup>1)</sup> When the sides may be partially invisible outside the browser window (in case which you would align content in de left div to the right, and vise versa), then I suggest the solution in **[this fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/23pLn/2/)** which does not require absolute positioning at all so that any content below the header is properly cleared in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right then this might be a possible solution.

```
​#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}

#center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #888888;
}
​
```

`#left` basically says that the element will be positioned absolute and *attached* to the left side with a *width* of `50%`. Same applies to `#right` just for the right side.

`#center` positions the element absolute pushed `50%` to the left and then with a negative margin of `width/2` which in your case would be `480px` to position it in the center.

The order of the elements in the HTML is important for this hack.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>​
```

The `#center` DIV ***must*** be the last element if you don't want to work with z-indexes.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mainerror/AXF5b/) to test it.

Comment: Sorry, but I broke it. Content in left and right div is gone, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/AXF5b/1/).

Comment: Clever! Seriously, +1, that's a great use of `position: absolute` =D

Comment: @NGLN Not sure if I'd call that _breaking_ it. There was no requirement for content in the left and right DIVs. Also, the content just disappears below the center DIV.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="Header_Container">
    <div class="Header_Side" id="Header_Left"></div>
    <div class="Header_Side" id="Header_Right"></div>
    <div id="Header_Center"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Header_Container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#Header_Container > div {
    height: 158px;                /* height of the image */
}

.Header_Side {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}

#Header_Left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}

#Header_Right {
    left: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}

#Header_Center {
    position: relative;
    width: 158px;                 /* width of the image */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url('...');
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BMAmJ/1/).

Comment: Sorry, but I think content in left and right div should remain visible, now it is [partialy obfuscated](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/BMAmJ/2/) by the center div.

Comment: Partially cover the sides does not contradict the question. :-) But adding margins (like e.g. in your answer) is a nicer solution.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9852630/757830) with a solution for partially covered sides which does not use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but you need to change your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/gG7r7/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id="header_background_container">
    <div id="header_left"></div>
    <div id="header_right"></div>
</div>
<div id="header_content_container">
    <div id="header_content"><p>Content goes here</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header_content_container {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header_content {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

#header_left {
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

#header_right {
  background: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. Content in right is obfuscated. [And where is left div](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/gG7r7/2/)?